# Firebase Authentication Issue with Emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, firebase-tools

I am building a site with a custom domain that uses and is hosted by Firebase. I use the Google and Anonymous authentication providers (with `signInWithRedirect`). Up until adding the custom domain, everything worked fine between the emulator and live site. I could log in with either and carry on my happy way. But once I added the custom domain, it all went wonky on my local emulator site (the live site is working just fine with anonymous and Google authentication).

My 'sign in' function, if it helps/matters:

```
document.getElementById('googleSignInButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Trigger the Google Sign-In redirect
    signInWithRedirect(auth, googleAuthProvider)
        .then((result) => {
            // The user is signed in with Google
            set(child(firebaseRef, `users/${auth.currentUser.uid}`), {
                email: auth.currentUser.email,
                "last-login": serverTimestamp()
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Google Sign-In Error:', error);
    });
});
```

On my local emulator site, I can log in anonymously only. If I try to login with Google, I am redirected to the Google sign-in page, select my account, and then I am returned. However, my local emulator site doesn't acknowledge the login (`OnAuthChanged` is never called), so it prompts me to log in. On the live site, it works just fine. But, if I log in anonymously (locally), then it works fine.

I have my custom domain added to my `firebaseConfig.authDomain`, the Google OAuth Credentials as an `Authorized redirect URI`, and in Firebase Authentication Authorized Domains. Again, the live site works just fine (with Google Auth Provider).

I am guessing the issue has something to do with the redirect to the live (custom) domain for authorization, so it cannot return to the localhost emulator, but again, it worked fine prior to the custom domain, so it was still hitting the live site as an `Authorized redirect URI`. I do not get any console errors (that I can see) or any indication something is wrong, other than still being prompted to log in, so it seems there is something in the talkback that I am missing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just set up a preview channel (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/test-preview-deploy) and I am having the same issue as locally with the emulator: I can log in anonymously, but Google sign-in does not trigger an authentication.

For kicks, I changed my `firebaseConfig.authDomain` back to the Firebase-provided URL (https://my-site.firebaseapp.com), and I can log in through the emulator, the preview channel, and the live channel. Definitely something with the custom domain.